# Firebase Java API with push utf8 string

Tags: java, utf-8, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using java to push string to firebase, the code is very simple:

```
Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.put("title", "Khao khát cuộc sống bình thường sau Masters 2016");
firebase.post("posts", dataMap);
```

But the result on firebase is:

```
title: "khao kh�t cu?c s?ng b�nh th??ng sau Masters 2016"
```

I don't want to convert the string to byte array before push to Firebase.
What is problem and how can I solve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The [Firebase Java SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html) doesn't have a method called `post()`, so I assume you're using some other library to write to the database. How are you writing to Firebase?

I just added the same text with the Java client:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/36776859");
Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.put("title", "Khao khát cuộc sống bình thường sau Masters 2016");
ref.updateChildren(dataMap);
```

and it shows up perfectly:

```
{
  "title": "Khao khát cuộc sống bình thường sau Masters 2016"
}
```

So most likely the client you are using is either breaking the text already or fails in how it transfer it to Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What client you are using? I'm use firebase4j by Brandon Gresham. And i think POST - Pushing Data still listed in REST API of Firebase. I'm also try to use PUT, but the result is the same. The reason i use POST instead of PUT is because i need the unique ID after save data to Firebase.

Comment: I'm using the Firebase Java SDK. See [this page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html) and find the "plain Java SDK" link.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason. It's because I'm using Java client **firebase4j by Brandon Gresham**. In that client, they are using StringEntity without set Charset. To fix it, just add StandardCharsets.UTF_8

In net/thegreshams/firebase4j/service/Firebase.java, line 422, modify:

```
result = new StringEntity(jsonData);
```

To

```
result = new StringEntity(jsonData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Keep in mind that this was impossible to know from the question because you didn't say what client library you are using. In general I highly recommend using the Firebase Java SDK I linked to, since it prevents many problems like this.